# How to display something similar to the quick assist menu?

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-plugin

I'd like to create a menu that is very similar to the quick assist menu.
It should also show up when the user hits a shortcut and list some actions based on the editor's current cursor position.

Additionally, it should be possible to register a selection listener on this menu in order to highlight some parts of the code that belongs to the selected action.

It would be really great if someone knows how to do something like this or if there is an eclipse plugin that implements a similar workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear regarding the targeted editor/language: If you are creating your very own editor, you can of course create arbitrary context menus using actions, commands, handlers and the like.

If you want to have your menu contributed to one of the existing editors, then it very much depends on that specific editor. E.g. the Java (JDT) or Javascript (JSDT) editors have specific extension points to contribute new quick assist entries: [JDT quick assist](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_jdt_ui_quickAssistProcessors.html?cp=3_1_1_32), [JSDT quick assist](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_wst_jsdt_ui_quickAssistProcessors.html).

Comment: Many thanks. The targeted editor is the Scala IDE which extends the JDT.
My problem is, that I do not want to add just a single Quick Assist Entry, but I want to create something like an additional Quick Assist menu.